# Getting error on a particular query on a table in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6, errors

I am getting the following error on one query in Postgres:

```
select * from sampletable where sample_id = 1234;
```

Error is :

```
ERROR: could not access status of transaction <some-id> 
Detail: CLOG segment 42 does not exist: No such file or directory.
```

But when I am trying to run other queries on the same table, it works fine.
Eg.

```
select * from sampletable where sample_id = 4321;
```

So, its happening for a particular value of a sample_id only.

What could be the cause of it and how can I fix it? Any suggestions.

Comment: What version of PostgreSQL? Have you tried restarting the database?

Comment: Its 9.6.8 version of PostgreSQL

Comment: You have some sort of corruption, but it is not entirely clear what caused it.  Hardware failures?  Running with fsync=off?  Software bugs?  Has the system ever been upgraded using pg_upgrade, and if so what was the original version? 
See https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Corruption

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CLOG is the PostgreSQL Commit Log Manager (CLog). It's telling you here that the record of transactions is fuxed. This may have been caused from any kind of corruption. I would back up the database before attempting anything. There is one [suggestion the lists,](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/AANLkTims48njGKkvkXHiTG6%3D19hQ31VFmFRPPLg%2B5w03%40mail.gmail.com)

> There is a commit log corruption in your database. You need to make the
>   files with right size (256K of zeroes). A suitable `dd` from `/dev/zero` will
>   accomplish this on modern Unixen (ie, anything that has `/dev/zero`). Filling
>   of those files with zeroes nothing but  *"all those old transactions are
>   aborted"*.
>
> The safest way to resolve the issue by using the below command:-
>
> ```
> dd if=/dev/zero of=Transaction_missing_file_of pg_clog bs=256K count=1
> ```
>
> (To make the uncommitted record as they haven't been committed).

This is followed up with the [amusing reply,](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/AANLkTikjzQe9SxGqHZ22z_znzr1wSn7%2BA%3DrGc2R4i2Zg%40mail.gmail.com)

> Just for the record, playing with pg_clog files like this is an
>   **insanely unsafe** thing to do. Notably it will make all aborted
>   transactions in that range become committed, leading to all sorts of
>   fun. This is a desperate measures only action and not one that looks
>   immediately related to the problem.

I would try backing up, upgrading to PostgreSQL 11, running `VACUUM FULL`, and restarting *before* I messed around with this in 9.6. But I would give it a shot if that failed.

Comment: Upgrading a corrupted cluster will not work. Note that the fake commit log files you are creating will make all affected rows disappear from the table. You could fill them with hex 55 bytes to pretend that all transactions have been committed.